# Ionic 4 lazy loaded route - module not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, ionic4

Im having a lot of issues with Ionic 4 and lazy loaded modules, for some reason it keeps reporting that the below login module cannot be found, if I edit the route.module.ts file and save sometimes it finds it. anyone come across this issue yet and know how to fix ?

```
error in app.module.ts Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './pages/auth/login/login.module'
Error: Cannot find module './pages/auth/login/login.module'
```

// main app module

```
        import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

        import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
        // AoT requires an exported function for factories
        export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
            return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/')
        }



        class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        handleError(error) {
            console.log("error in app.module.ts", error);
        }
        }


        @NgModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        entryComponents: [],
        imports: [ 
            BrowserModule,
            IonicModule.forRoot(),
            AppRoutingModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            }),
            AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
            }),
            AngularFireDatabaseModule,
            // Put your custom imports below this line to make merges in Git easier   
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            ],   
        providers: [
                {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}, // had to add a custom error handler class here as IonicErrorHandler deprecated - 
                { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule {}
```

// main Routes file lazy loading the login page that cant be found

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

        const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
        ];

        @NgModule({
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
        ],
        exports: [RouterModule]
        })
        export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

// login lazyloaded module that cant be found

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
        import { TranslateModule} from "@ngx-translate/core"
        import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

        import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

        const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            component: LoginPage
        }
        ];

        @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            IonicModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,    
            TranslateModule,
            RouterModule.forChild(routes)
        ],
        declarations: [LoginPage]
        })
        export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Angular's folder structure and check that that module has a correctly path then try reload your server when your path lazy module has correcly path.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the structure is totally fine

Comment: Try remove  { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules } an restart your server for a second for a test and  don't use aot.

Comment: How to disable AOT in ionic 4 ?

Comment: The only way of "activate" aot is using ng serve --aot  if you never use this command is recommended when you want inspect all application errors maybe this error is a consequence of another error. Could you reproduce this error with stackblitz ? and share here?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your CLI.

run `ionic serve` (I use `ionic serve` most of the time, others seem to use `ng serve`).

I have noticed that the CLI needs restarting from time to time, especially when making changes to the `app.module` file.

I recreated your error message just now by removing `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';` then letting the CLI recompile (at this point i got `ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[IonRouterOutlet -> Router]:`).

When i imported the `AppRoutingModule` again and just let the CLI compile (*without restarting*) i go the exact same message you got; restarted it and my project loaded perfectly.

Now whenever i get some silly error i restart the CLI before i scratch a hole in the side of my head.

Comment: It’s not really a solution to have to restart the CLI every time. AnywY I need to restart and modify a file every time I want to compile my code - surely there’s a better way

Comment: did that fix your issue? but i agree, there should be a better way and i am sure the IONIC team will look into it if there isn't one available already.